# Use of ngraph.path library in Palantir - Foundry

Tags: typescript, palantir-foundry

I'm trying to utilise the aStar algorithm in the ngraph.path library in Palantir - Foundry. With the problems I've had, I'm wondering if the library, or at least the aStar function, is incompatible with Palantir. Any help anyone can give me is much appreciated.

This is error I get when I try and run the Typescript function I've written.

```
(0 , a.default) is not a function.
Error Parameters: {}
TypeError: (0 , a.default) is not a function
    at u.Optimum_Path (UserCode:28:66486)
    at te.executeFunctionInternal (FunctionsIsolateRuntimePackage:2:910734)
    at Oe (FunctionsIsolateRuntimePackage:2:909762)
    at async te.executeFunction (FunctionsIsolateRuntimePackage:2:910105)
    at async userFunction (FunctionsInitialization:8:43)
```

This is the function I wrote:

```
import { Function, Integer, Double, Float,OntologyEditFunction , Edits, DoublePropertyBaseType, GeoPoint  } from "@foundry/functions-api";
import { Objects, Ports, Nodes, Edges} from "@foundry/ontology-api";
import createGraph from 'ngraph.graph';
import * as ngraph from 'ngraph.path';

import { aggregateNode } from "@foundry/functions-typescript-runtime-internal-api";

interface Node {
    id: string;
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}

interface Edge {
    source: string;
    target: string;
    distance: number; 
   
}

type NodeId = string | number; 

interface GraphNode {
    id: NodeId; 
}

interface GraphLink {
    data: {
        length: number; 
    };
}
export class MyFunctions {

    @Function()
    public async Optimum_Path(start_node_id: string, end_node_id: string): Promise<string> {

        const graph = createGraph();

        const nodes_data: Nodes[] = Objects.search().nodes().all();
        const edges_data: Edges[] = Objects.search().edges().all();

        nodes_data.forEach((node: Nodes) => {
            graph.addNode(node.nodeId, { lat: node.latitude, lon: node.longitude });
        });

        edges_data.forEach((edge: Edges) => {
            if (typeof edge.endNodeId !== 'undefined') {
            graph.addLink(edge.startNodeId, edge.endNodeId, { length: edge.distance })};
        });

        const pathFinder = ngraph.aStar(graph);
        
        const optimal_path = pathFinder.find(start_node_id, end_node_id);

        return `Optimal path from ${start_node_id} to ${end_node_id}: ${JSON.stringify(optimal_path)}`;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why that would not work. Can you add console.log() to validate what is the state of the different variables, for example console.log(nodes_data) etc. You can see the logs at the bottom in a tab, when you run it in preview.

Comment: Hi ZettaP. Really appreciate you responding to this. It's encouraging that you can't see why it shouldn't work in theory. I added "console.log(node_data)" to the function, but couldn't see the output in any of the tabs at the button when I ran it in preview unfortunatelty.

Comment: Can you try to change the imports ? Like import { createGraph } from 'ngraph.graph';
instead

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Zetta. When I did that, it said “Module ‘“ngraph.graph”’ has no exported member ‘createGraph’.